# How to fail AWS Code Pipeline deployment when ECS Circuit Breaker triggers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

We currently utilize aws codepipeline with a cloudformation deploy stage that deploys updates including ECS services.

Whenever there's a deployment failure, ECS gracefully rollbacks to the last stable version after several attempts, thanks to the Circuit Breaker feature.

However, cloudformation records this as successful, thus our pipeline results in a successful deployment regardless if ECS is successful or not.

Is there a way to fail the deployment of the Code Pipeline whenever the circuit breaker triggers?